# "Product" topology of $\mathbb N\times \mathbb R$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, elementary-number-theory, continuity, contest-math

**Background:** Consider a set that is a finite or countable set (for example $\mathbb N$) endowed with discrete topology

**Question:** What topology is endowed with $\mathbb N\times \mathbb R$? Is $\mathbb N\times\mathbb R$ connected?

Is it possible to define a reasonable topology such that $\mathbb N\times\mathbb R$ is connected?

**Motivation:** "Connectness" is a useful property that is a necessary condition for many theorems. In order to apply those theorems in discrete space $\mathbb N$, one may want try to "connectify" the discrete space, for example, by "put it together" with $\mathbb R$.

**My guess:** $\mathbb N\times\mathbb R$ is not connected by its standard product topology. Consider set $\{1\}\times\mathbb R$ and $(\mathbb N\setminus \{1\})\times\mathbb R$, both of those sets are open by the standard product topology as $\mathbb R$ and $\{1\}$ are both open sets.

In order to make $\mathbb N\times\mathbb R$ connected, can we force define that the whole set $\mathbb R$ to be neither closed nor open? Intuitively, take a closed interval $[0,1)$, then $\mathbb N\times [0,1)$ can only be connected?

Additionally, I am not sure if things like $\mathbb N\times \mathbb R$ is connected. Any comments will help!

Comment: You mention $X$ in the first line and then never mention it again. Anyway your guess is correct, and the proof is perfectly correct.

Comment: @Wojowu sorry, editing

Comment: @HighGPA: $\Bbb N\times[0,1]$ is not connected in the product topology. Indeed, as long as $\Bbb N$ is given the discrete topology, $\Bbb N\times X$ is not connected unless $X$ is the empty space.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Yes you are definitely right. Even $\mathbb N\times [0,1)$ is not connected, unless we redefine the meaning of "product topology". Since the "product topology" is already the coarsest, redefining a reasonable topology such that $N\times R$ is connected seems near impossible...

Comment: The usual way of obtaining a (path) connected space from an arbitrary topological space is by making it a part of a [cone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cone_(topology)), not a simple product.

Comment: @tomasz Many thanks for your help. How do I make $N$ part of a cone?

Comment: @HighGPA: There's a definition in the article I linked...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to make N×R connected is to give N the indiscrete topology.

Comment: For example how? Is it possible to define a new "product" topology which is neither box topology nor Tychonoff topology?

Comment: @HighGPA? The product of two connected spaces is connected.

Comment: I guess you are right. Though "indiscrete topology" seems to be a trivial topology and not too meaningful...

Comment: There are others which any @HighGPA student can create.

Answer (score 1):

Why forcing properties on the topology of $\mathbb R$ when $\mathbb R$ is already connected?

The obstruction in $\mathbb N\times \mathbb R$ connection is clearly the fact that $\mathbb N$ itself is not connected (which is what you used to prove that the product is not connected, i.e., being $\{1\}$ open in $\mathbb N$, you conclude that $\{1\}\times\mathbb R$ is open in $\mathbb N\times\mathbb R$), therefore I'd say that the easiest way to get to a connected topology on $\mathbb N\times \mathbb R$ is requiring a connected $\mathbb N$ (for instance, giving it the trivial topology, i.e. $\{\varnothing,\mathbb N\}$).

If your question requires us to keep the discrete topology on $\mathbb N$, I'm afraid that changing the topology of $\mathbb R$ won't be much of a help. You could always take a clopen set of $\mathbb N$ (e.g., $\{1\}$), and its product with any other topological space will still be a clopen in the product topology.